# Python TypeError: plotdatehist() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, typeerror

apologies beforehand if this is a stupid question...

I've been using some Manchester University code to record, analyse, and graphically display bird box activity using IR emitters/receivers using a Raspberry Pi.
Anyway, I've run into a problem in the graphical display part.

The part of the code causing the error is:

```
intervalsize = 20*60

histogramBins = math.ceil(float(numberOfSeconds)/float(intervalSize))

#draw the graph
fig = plotDatehist(events, bins=histogramBins,title="Bird Box Activity", intervalSize=intervalSize)
```

and the error which keeps coming up reads

```
TypeError:plotDatehist() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bins'
```

I've heard that similar problems can be fixed by updating software, but as far as I can tell everything is up to date.

Comment: The plotDatehist method doesn't have a bins argument. Where did you get this method from?

Comment: This book http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1118555430/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=1118555430&linkCode=as2&tag=pifaceopenlx-21

Comment: It was written by someone from the University of Manchester, the part I posted was copied verbatim from it, I can't imagine why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you try posting the method signature (it's "def" line)? If you don't have it, try `import inspect` and then `print(inspect.getargspec(plotDateHist))`

Comment: It says  `def plotDatehist(dates, binCount, title=None, intervalSize=None):`

Comment: So that method doesn't have a `bins` parameter, as you can plainly see. Why are you trying to pass one?

Comment: I assumed it would work if it was in the book, would it work if I added 'bins' to that line then?